# Put columns in center if there are less columns than full row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to **Bootstrap**

I have a HTML like:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    First Column
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    Second Column
  </div>
</div>
```

Now there are only two columns of 3 size each and will not cover the full length of the row so there will be blank space at the right side of the row on the view.

These columns are dynamic like these may be One, two, three or may be four in a row at a time.

I want this, **if there are less then four columns with size 3 in the row, those columns should be in center of the row instead of left side and blank space in right side.**

Please suggest, how can I manage this kind of case?

Comment: Add the class "col-lg-offset-3" to your first row. That will center it if you have only two lg-3 rows

Comment: The number of columns may be 1,2,3 or 4  any number of columns can be come at a time there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your requirement and if you are just new to bootstrap, I will recommend you to implement **[bootstrap4](https://getbootstrap.com/)**, as this framework is based on **Flexbox** and its very easy to align the columns here

**Reference:**

- [Bootstrap Grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)
- [Bootstrap Flex Utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/)

```css
.col-3 {
  padding-top: .75rem;
  padding-bottom: .75rem;
  background-color: rgba(86, 61, 124, .15);
  border: 1px solid rgba(86, 61, 124, .2);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-3">1</div>
    <div class="col-3">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

But if you are working in a code that already using bootstrap3 and can't switch to bootstrap4, use a custom class of yours in `row` and use `flexbox`

```css
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-row .col-xs-3 {
  padding-top: .75rem;
  padding-bottom: .75rem;
  background-color: rgba(86, 61, 124, .15);
  border: 1px solid rgba(86, 61, 124, .2);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row flex-row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Bhuwan, But I'm working on a code that is using bootstrap-3, is this will be helpful in there also?

Answer (score 2):

```css
.row {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
        First Column
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
        Second Column
  </div>
</div>
```

you can use offset class or just add these css

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: This is not working bro, display flex snoozes my columns